# how to add a value of array for a specified index without replacing it?

Tags: java, arrays, loops

THIS IS ONE METHOD CLASS ONLY .

```
        System.out.print("1. Add Customer..............................................P500.00\n");
        case 1://Add Customer

            for (int x = 0; x < CustomerInfo.length; x++){// Start For Records
                x++;
                System.out.print("\nConfimation Number: ");
                CustomerInfo[x][0][0][0][0][0] = br.readLine();
                System.out.print("\nFirst Name: ");
                CustomerInfo[x][1][0][0][0][0] = br.readLine();
                System.out.print("Last Name: ");
                CustomerInfo[x][0][1][0][0][0] = br.readLine();
                System.out.print("Guest: ");
                CustomerInfo[x][0][0][1][0][0] = br.readLine();
                System.out.print("Night: ");
                CustomerInfo[x][0][0][0][1][0] = br.readLine();
                System.out.print("Accommodation: ");
                CustomerInfo[x][0][0][0][0][1] = br.readLine();
                System.out.println();
                break;
            }

            break;


            for (int x = 0; x < CustomerInfo.length; x++){

                if (CustomerInfo[x][0][0][0][0][0] != null){
                if (CustomerInfo[x][1][0][0][0][0] != null){
                if (CustomerInfo[x][0][1][0][0][0] != null){
                if (CustomerInfo[x][0][0][1][0][0] != null){
                if (CustomerInfo[x][0][0][0][1][0] != null){
                if (CustomerInfo[x][0][0][0][0][1] != null){


                System.out.print("\n|---------------------------------------------------------------------|\n");
                System.out.print("\n\nConfirmation Number:      |--------------->  " +   CustomerInfo[x][0][0][0][0][1]);
                System.out.print("\nGuest Name:                 |--------------->  " + CustomerInfo[x][1][0][0][0][0] + " " + CustomerInfo[x][0][1][0][0][0]);
                System.out.print("\nNumber Of Guest:            |--------------->  " + CustomerInfo[x][0][0][1][0][0]);
                System.out.print("\nNumber Of Nights:           |--------------->  " + CustomerInfo[x][0][0][0][1][0]);
                System.out.println("\nAccommodations:               |--------------->  " + CustomerInfo[x][0][0][0][0][1]);
```

i add customer for first time then if i add customer for the second time the first customer wasn't recorded.

i noticed that the problem is the increment.

```
 for (int x = 0; x < CustomerInfo.length; x++)
```

because i use break after that.

```
break;
```

but i want to accomplish is to add customer and when i add another one the previous should display along with the new.

what i asked is i want to add more array values one after one . or like after i add value to my '[x]' i want to add again, but not at the same time

any suggestions ?

i really need your help.

Comment: `CustomerInfo[x][0][0][0][0][0]` No no no no no no. My eyes. Must destroy them to unsee the abomination.

Comment: is it not valid sir ? @John3136

Comment: i'm new in java, sorry i i got mistakes.

Comment: A 6 dimensional array may be valid, but it is never sane! I'd go so far as to say it is never the right solution to a problem, but then there is probably one theoretical physicist out there somewhere who can make a valid case that I'm wrong... Without knowing what `CustomerInfo` is, this is impossible to answer - I'm not even sure what you're asking...

Comment: should i go for 2 dimensional ? or what can you suggest ? i just really need to fix this .

Comment: what i asked is i want to add more array values one after one .
or like after i add value to my '[x]' i want to add again, but not at the same time.

Comment: I repeat: without knowing what `CustomerInfo` is, this is unanswerable. I suspect you don't actually have a 6D array and are just have some bad syntax. I still have no idea what you are trying to do. `i want to add more array values one after one . or like after i add value to my '[x]' i want to add again, but not at the same time` makes no sense.

Comment: `CustomerInfo` is an array that holds the value of Customers .

Answer (score 1):

You probably meant to declare `CustomerInfo` as follows:

```
String[] customerInfo = new String[6];
```

and have each array - hold the information of one customer, where first-name will be stored on the first index, last-name on the second and etc.

By doing something like `CustomerInfo[][][][][][]` - the code tries to declare/access a multidimensional (6-dimensional) array - which is probably *not* what you wanted.

Now Java is an object oriented programming language, so instead of multidimensional arrays you should try to design your code to use objects - it will make your code easier to read and maintain.

So first, create a CustomerInfo class:

```
class CustomerInfo {
    String confirmationNumber;
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    String guest;
    String night;
    String accommodation;

    public CustomerInfo(String confirmationNumber,
                        String firstName,
                        String lastName,
                        String guest,
                        String night,
                        String accommodation) {
        this.confirmationNumber = confirmationNumber;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.guest = guest;
        this.night = night;
        this.accommodation = accommodation;
    }
}
```

and now that you have such a "holder" for the data, you can read the user input and save it into a list of `CustomerInfo`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ...
    List<CustomerInfo> customerInfos = new ArrayList<CustomerInfo>();
    for (int i = 0; i < customerInfos.length; i++){// Start For Records
        System.out.print("\Confirmation Number: ");
        String confirmationNumber = br.readLine();
        System.out.print("\nFirst Name: ");
        String firstName = br.readLine();
        System.out.print("Last Name: ");
        String lastName = br.readLine();
        System.out.print("Guest: ");
        String guest = br.readLine();
        System.out.print("Night: ");
        String night = br.readLine();
        System.out.print("Accommodation: ");
        String accommodation = br.readLine();
        CustomerInfo customer = new CustomerInfo(confirmationNumber, firstName, lastName, guest, night, accommodation);
        customerInfos.add(customer);
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

and if you want to do even better, add some validations on top, for example, if `guest` is a number, you can read it as `int` or try to parse it as an `int` - and if the user entered something weird - display a proper error message. And etc.

Comment: We don't know what `CustomerInfo` is, so while everything you said is true I'm not convinced we know enough to answer the actual question. I suspect OP doesn't actually have a 6D array...

Comment: ill try to use it, but if possible it should be one method class..
prof says .

Comment: @John3136 I humbly disagree... one of the main problems in the code is the use of (nested) arrays and incorrect increment of `x` which creates "gaps" inside the array and which probably also causes an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. The code will be easier to deal with if the OP will switch to List. No need to deal with indexes as well as the size is not final.

Comment: @John3136 see the first paragraph that was added to the answer - for clarification.

Comment: @Geoddie the `main` method can be declared inside class `CustomerInfo` - there's no contradiction there.

Comment: @alfasin im very sorry but i really dont know how to use methods, im a freshmen student i we didnt come-up yet at the methods.

im sorry if i waste your effort .

very very sorry sir .

Answer (score 0):

```
    case 1://Add Customer

        for (int x = 0; x < CustomerInfo.length; x++){// Start For Records
            **x++;**
```

You have problem with your loop. You increase your incremental variable when you start loop and when you finish loop two times.

That means you start not with 0 but with 1. But you want to check that if there is a customer at 0.

Comment: i was just experimenting about the increment but the result is the same, it always display 1 customer even though i added 1 it means there are two customer.